# Two names for a column

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a column named `foo` in a table. I have constructed queries in scripts, which use this name.

I would now like to rename the column in the table to `bar`. This will break the scripts (there are several, but they could be changed if necessary). The table is referenced by other tables. I'd like to rename because the context of what is stored in that column has changed.

Is it possible to have two names for a column?

Comment: Is the column foo a unique column name in the database, i.e. not found on other tables? Do you have functions and views using the column or just scripts on your terminal and/or application? Would a find-replace for your scripts be a feasible option? If not, why not?

Answer (score 8):

I will assume your table is named `baz` and is in schema `public`

```
create table baz (
  foo text primary key
);

insert into baz (foo) values ('hello');

select foo from baz;
```

Now you want to rename that column:

```
alter table baz rename column foo to bar;
```

But now your scripts are broken:

```
select foo from baz; -- nope!
```

So create a new schema, put a view in it, and alter your `search_path` to hide the table "behind" the view.

```
create schema qux;

create or replace view qux.baz as 
    select
      bar as foo
    from public.baz;

set search_path to qux, public;

select foo from baz; -- works!
```

This is kind of the postgres way to do `create synonym`

Comment: This won't work if the script does inserts/updates into this column.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what you do exactly in your scripts, there are ways to work around it. I'll assume `SELECT` only for the purpose of this answer. But `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` are possible, too ...

#### `VIEW`

A **[`VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html)** would be an option, [like @Andriy commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6965/andriy-m). If you need the current table to stay in place as is, things get more complicated, but still *possible*. You could mask the table with **a `VIEW` of the same name in another schema** listed before the schema of the table in the schema **`search_path`**. I actually did that on several occasions to preserve interfaces I could not adapt after updates to the DB schema.

Basic sample code:

```
CREATE SCHEMA override;

CREATE VIEW override.tbl AS
SELECT *, foo AS bar       -- to add the column a second time
    -- tbl_id, foo AS bar  -- to replace the column
FROM tbl;
```

Only grant the `USAGE` privilege on the schema to `public` to avoid abuse:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA override TO public;
```

Put `override` as 1st schema in your `search_path` and your original query "magically" includes another column.
If you don't want to mess with people's `search_path`, you can do that dynamically in your scripts at the start of each session:

```
DO
$$BEGIN
EXECUTE (SELECT 'SET search_path = override,' || setting
         FROM pg_catalog.pg_settings WHERE name = 'search_path');
END$$;
```

This is safe against SQL injection, because the subquery returns a valid search path.

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the “current schema”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)

Similar use case masking a function:

- [How can I fake inet_client_addr() for unit tests in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69988/how-can-i-fake-inet-client-addr-for-unit-tests-in-postgresql/70009#70009)

#### `TEMPORARY VIEW`

Or you can just create a temporary view to mask the table:

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW tbl AS
SELECT *, foo AS bar FROM tbl;
```

Temporary objects are only visible inside the same session and die with it.

You may need to do more for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`. Most utility commands (DML) can't be fooled like that.

#### "Generated column"

Postgres does not have generated columns *per se*, but you can use a function that looks and works just like one:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (tbl_id int, foo text);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1, 'hello');

CREATE FUNCTION bar(tbl) RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS 'SELECT $1.foo';

SELECT *, t.bar
FROM   tbl t;
```

Detailed explanation:

- [Make column default a query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56549/make-column-default-a-query/56572#56572)
- [Store common query as column?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11166268/939860)

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6d108/2)